# c# how to send an authentication request to REST Api

Tags: c#, api, rest, cookies, curl

I am trying to make a **(C# .net 4.5 winforms)** application that need to get Json from an API.
I have been trying and googling for 2 days now with no luck!

Note: I do not want to use Async!
Note: It does not have to be WebClient.

All i have to go on is this documented cURL request:

```
curl -k -d "username=<USERNAME>@<AUTHTYPE>&password=<PASS>"  https://<URL>:<PORT>/api/json/access/ticket 
{ "data": { 
  "CSRFPreventionToken":"4EEC61E2:lwk7od06fa1+DcPUwBTXCcndyAY",  
  "ticket":"User:4EEC61E2::rsKoApxDTLYPn6H3NNT6iP2mv...", 
  "username":"<USERNAME>"}
}
```

I am trying to use WebClient to get the Json response, but i keep getting:

```
Exception: "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized"
```

Here is my initial code:

```
string result = "";
            var conn = "https://" + server.Hostname + ":" + server.Port + "/api2/json";
            var query = conn + "/access/ticket";
            var json = "";
            try
            {
                // Accept Self-Signed SSL Certificate
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
                // Get Json
                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                    json = client.DownloadString(query);
                    result = json;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var BrPoint = e.ToString();
            }

            return result;
```

Now i need to send Authentication with that request (like in the curl one) but how??

And when i have the Ticket, i need to make a cookie containing the ticket to send the next request.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like its because you're doing a Get request with the DownloadString() method call rather than a POST request using the UploadString() method call.

Try changing it to UploadString() and passing the following as the data parameter:

```
username=<USERNAME>@<AUTHTYPE>&password=<PASS>
```

Comment: Amazing works!  Still some problems though! but that really helped alot :D